# Microsoft access visual basic automatic every night

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, sharepoint, office365

Can anyone help me
I have MS Access 2013
And Sharepoint online (office 365) and I need to take data from on prime Database SQL to SP online, I use Access to do it but it is manual and I need it automatic overnight anyone had an idea how we can do it.
And I use MS VB
these are the code:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub DeleteAdd_Click()

  On Error Resume Next

  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  DoCmd.OpenQuery "DeleteTest", acViewNormal, acEdit
  DoCmd.SetWarnings True
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  DoCmd.OpenQuery "AddTest", acViewNormal, acEdit
  DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub

Private Sub lisACTORS_Click()

  MsgBox lisACTORS.Value
End Sub
```

Anyway I can do it in VB or task Schedule

Comment: You can try using a timer that ticks every hour for example and check if the hour equals midnight, and then execute your code.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in a Windows Forms Application before, I'm not sure what type of application you are running. You add a Timer control, make the timer enabled and set the timer interval to 60 * 1000 = 60000 (equivalent to one hour). Then in the Timer.Tick event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx), write:

```
If Now.Hour.ToString = "23" Then 'Checks if the current hour is midnight
    'Execute code
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Obl, I have delete query after that I have add query and I need to run those 2 queries overnight

Comment: So where I put 'Execute code' is where you put your code for delete query and add query. That way, those two things will happen sometime between 12:00AM and 1:00AM. You will also have to keep your program running for this to work. If I answered your question, I would appreciate you to mark it as the answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Obl, I try and I don't success still not working with me

Answer (score 0):

I used to do this at a former job I had a few years back.  Follow these steps . . .

```
Create an AutoExec macro

If you have already created a macro that contains the actions that you want to occur when the database starts, just rename the macro AutoExec, and it will run the next time that you open the database. Otherwise, follow these steps to create a macro:

    On the Create tab, in the Other group, click Macro. If this command is unavailable, click the arrow beneath either the Module or the Class Module button, and then click Macro.

    In the Macro Builder, in the first empty Action cell, select the action that you want to perform. If applicable, under Action Arguments, type the appropriate values in the argument boxes.

    If you cannot find the action you want, on the Design tab, in the Show/Hide group, make sure Show All Actions is selected. This expands the list of actions that you can use, but the list will include some actions that will only run if the database is granted trusted status. For more information, see the articles Decide whether to trust a database or How database objects behave when trusted and untrusted.

    Repeat step 2 for each additional action you want to occur.

    Click Save, and in the Save As dialog box, type AutoExec.

    Click OK and then close the Macro Builder. The new macro will run the next time that you open the database.
```

To trigger the whole thing, you need to use the Windows Task Scheduler.  See the link below for all details.

https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html

Post back if you have additional questions about this process.